# Can MS Graph API read emails of outlook in(UTC+5:30) timezone?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am Reading emails of my mailbox and trying to reply them.
the mailbox is configured for my timezone(UTC+5:30) but the graph API is reading emails in UTC time zone.

So when am trying to send send reply from graph API the "**sent :**" field in trail mail is coming as UTC time.

Can you please help with the solution ?? **How can I read emails of my mailbox in UTC+5:30 time using graph API ??**

[Please find the image showing the time difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBB36.png)

Comment: In the browser image where you view the reply mail, is that browser on a computer in a different time zone than your mailbox configuration?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, this is currently not supported.

I think what you want is similar to the [functionality available to events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) where you can specify your time zone preference for the start and end datetime in the response body. I think this requires a [feature request](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests).